Agrupar elementos de dibujo en Java en una nueva clase sin perder las coordenadas de ninguno
He creado dos clases que extienden a JPanel, cada una de las cuales dibuja un rectángulo de diferentes dimensiones, que luego contendrán datos de diferentes tablas.
Código del primer rectángulo:
public class Cabecera extends JPanel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4708627107433326366L;

public Cabecera() {
    
}

public void dibujar(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    
    //Recuadro Mayor
    g2.translate(99.05, 70.75);
    g2.drawRect(getX(), getY(), 481, 77);
    
    //Rectángulo grande al medio
    g2.drawRect(224, getY(), 34, 77);
    //Rectángulo chico al medio (dentro del rectángulo anterior)
    g2.drawRect(224, getY(), 34, 37);
    
}

/*
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
   
    //Recuadro Mayor
    g2d.translate(96.22, 65.09);
    g2d.drawRect(getX(), getY(), 481, 77);
    
    //Rectángulo grande al medio
    g2d.drawRect(224, getY(), 34, 77);
    //Rectángulo chico al medio (dentro del rectángulo anterior)
    g2d.drawRect(224, getY(), 34, 37);
    
}
*/

//Probar el dibujo
/*
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Probar JPanel");
    Cabecera cabecera = new Cabecera();
    
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.add(cabecera);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
*/

Código del segundo rectángulo:
public class CuerpoPrincipal extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8945035292223709047L;

    public CuerpoPrincipal() {
    
    }
    

    public void dibujar(Graphics g) {


        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.translate(0,0);
    
        //Recuadro Mayor
        g2d.translate(25.47, 113.2);
        //g2d.translate(25.47, 169.80);
    
        //g2d.drawRect(getX(), getY(), 552, 484);
        g2d.drawRect(getX(), getY(), 484, 552);
    
    
    }

}

Al probar la impresión por separado (como verán en el código comentado de la primera clase), ambos se imprimen correctamente, pero cuando los pruebo en una nueva clase, agregando ambos, se desfasan en la pantalla.
Código de la clase de prueba:
public class VentanaPruebaCabecera extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Cabecera cabecera;
    private CuerpoPrincipal cuerpoPrincipal;

    public VentanaPruebaCabecera() {
        cabecera = new Cabecera();
        cuerpoPrincipal = new CuerpoPrincipal();

        setTitle("Prueba de Cabecera");
        setSize(595, 842);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new DrawingPanel());
    }

    class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            cabecera.dibujar(g);
            cuerpoPrincipal.dibujar(g);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new VentanaPruebaCabecera().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

La ejecución de esta última clase muestra lo siguiente:

El rectángulo de arriba tiene que estar más a la derecha que el de abajo, sin embargo, se corre hacia la izquierda (como guía tienen las medidas en cada una de las clases)
Desde ya, agradezco su valioso tiempo.
¿Cómo puedo integrar varios de estos dibujos en una única clase sin perder la ubicación original?
